# Using Like operator in SQL Server does 'Ename like '[A-Z]%' and 'Ename like '[a-z]%' mean same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am little bit confused for the Question stating that "First character should be capital in a column".

I tried using LIKE function for the Question "First character should be '+' or numeric" as `select * from emp where mobile like '+%' or mobile like '[0-9]%';`

Comment: If you're using a case insensitive collation, yes, they are the same. If you aren't, they are not. If you are using a binary collation, they also are not.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment, this all depends on the collation you are using. If you are using a case insensitive collation then  `LIKE '[A-Z]'` and `LIKE '[a-z]'` are synonyms as for comparison purposes the case of the letter doesn't matter. For a case sensitive or binary collation, however, this is not the case and the 2 expressions will result in different results.

So, for 3 example collations you can see that one returns `1`, while the other two return `0`:

```sql
SELECT CASE 'A' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI WHEN 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CaseInsensitiveCollation,
       CASE 'A' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI WHEN 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CaseSensitiveCollation,
       CASE 'A' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN WHEN 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BinaryCollation;
```

Comment: Ok I've now changed the collation for my db to Case Sensitive but my query is not getting executed correctly - select * from Emp where Ename like '[A-Z]%';   is giving the same result as of Ename like '[a-z]%'

Comment: Then you are using a case insensitive collation, as I demonstrate, @GursharanSingh .

Comment: What does `SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Emp' AND COLUMN_NAME = N'Ename';` return, @GursharanSingh ?

Comment: Iam sure I changed it to Case Sensitive by right clicking on db -> properties -> options -> select Latin1_General_CS_AI

Comment: No rows? Then you aren't running that in the correct database, @GursharanSingh , as according to your above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261311/using-like-operator-in-sql-server-does-ename-like-a-z-and-ename-like-a/66261558?noredirect=1#comment117153582_66261558) the table is called `Emp`, the column `Ename`, and I *assume* the schema is `dbo` as you have omitted it.

Comment: The Query given by you shows CI  but in settings its CS.. please help me out in this problem.

Comment: Then you haven't altered the column, @GursharanSingh; though like I showed you might be better off with the `COLLATE` operator. Changing the collation of the column should really only be done if you plan to change the rest of the databases.